# Monitoring the collectd instance availability in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, collectd

I am using kibana to monitor application logs and various system metric.

```
  Application logs --> filebeats

                            \
                             \
                              Logstash -> elasticsearch -> kibana 
                             /
                            /

**System metrics   --> collectd**
```

**Collectd** collects metrics from 5 different machines and feeds to logstash. It is difficult to understand from the dashboard if one of the machines is down, unless we explicity search for the entries from that machine.
Hence we need some way to show the user that the instance is down where the collectd is installed  (basically to tell if the machine is up or not)

Can anyone please suggest how I  can **notify in kibana that one of the collectd instances is down**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A visualisation could work, with an aggregation on the instances.

For example this is one visualisation we are using to check how our logstash are working.

[image]

Comment: Yes.. this is one of the approaches which can be used to decide if the instances are up . In addition to this we also made use of the table chart, that plotted the host against the count. So if the count showed 0, then it means the instance where the collectd is installed is down.